# WPF application causes Windows crash when returning from standby

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application and have recently started testing it on a machine with Windows XP Tablet edition. The application runs Full screen. When the computer goes into standby while my application is still running, returning from standby causes the igxprd32 display driver to stop working. When this happens I get a "Windows - Display Driver Stopped Responding" message, the resolution drops, and the colors get all messed up.

Instead of waiting for the computer to go into standby on it's own I've also test manually putting it into standby via the start menu. Bring the computer out of standby after this usually results in Windows crashing with a blue screen.

This only seems to happen on Windows XP Tablet edition.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Apparently what I was told was wrong. The machine actually is running XP Professional,
using the Mobile Intel 945 Chipset Family. I installed the latest drivers from the Intel website, this didn't fix the problem. I did find that if you google "igxprd32" you find there are many people who have problems with this driver.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too obvious but, have you checked for a more up-to-date driver?  I've seen this as the answer to similar problems on the MSDN WPF forum.